# mDNS instead of IP in /etc/hosts?

Tags: networking, ping, hosts, mdns

I have a laptop that I want to communicate with from my other PC. Sometimes I need to connect with this laptop for various tasks (ssh, scp, ping, to reach some locally hosted website, etc. - dev stuff in general).

This laptop has a hostname, which is long and hard to rememeber (and I cannot change it, because it's a work laptop).

I'd like to be able to create a a kind of alias for this laptop, so that when I do `ping thinkpad` it would actually do `ping XY-5-4-dfws-5.local` (the actual hostname of this laptop looks something like that).

I heard about `hosts` file aliases while googling, but it seems that this solution will not work in many cases, because it expects the client applications to use some specific call to get the actual address, and not all applications do that.
Is there an alternative?

Comment: There are a few alternatives, but you should be fine with `hosts` for the apps you mentioned. The `hosts` file syntax requires you to define an IP address to a hostname though, which means it won't change thinkpad.local to XY-5-4-dfws-5.local. You can work around it on most routers by defining a static dhcp entry for your notebook (instructions will differ based on your router model), so that it will always get, eg. 192.168.0.10, as IP. Once that is done just add `192.168.0.10 thinkpad.local` to your own hosts file and then `ping thinkpad.local` and `ssh thinkpad.local` should work.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about static IP. I wondered if I can set this up without touching the router's config.

Comment: If you're OK with reconfiguring your router, check if it allows setting a custom hostname for the device, then you don't need to modify /etc/hosts.